# How to create a hash table utilizing objects from a Linked List in Java

Tags: java, hash, linked-list, hashtable

I apologize if this is a repeat question, but I have searched this site and Google and YouTube for an answer to my problem with no luck. I am in a programming class, Data Structures, and our first assignment was to write a base program that reads in a CSV file and stores the data into a Linked List. The file contains information from a fundraiser, so it has name, country, contribution amount, and a unique ID. The first program was easy, I have no programming experience outside of college classes I have taken, but this wasn't too hard. However, the assignment for this week is making my head spin....here are the details of the assignment:

"At this point, you decide to implement a Hash structure for the contributor data to prepare for searches. You will read the contributor information from a file provided; it is a comma delimited (CSV) file. As each record is read, create a Hash table for the ID field. The limitation for the Hash table is that it has a size of 5, so you need to be able to handle collisions. Collisions should be resolved through the use of a linked list for the ID values (implement this using a stack). Your design should include the following:

A Hash table pointing to a structure for a linked list that contains only the following information:

Each Hash Bucket Collision Item will have the following Information:

ID: Integer; //identifier key for future needs

Hash Bucket Functions/Methods:

Input constructor: //to accept a string for the name and additional information for each contributor (you will only need the ID portion of the input data)
Hash Function constructor: (Hint: You only have 5 Hash buckets, so the function can be a very simple calculation.)
Pop constructor
Push constructor
Print constructor: //to show the contents of a Hash bucket"

So...first issue, every example of a hash table that I can find in Java has people passing over an array in the hashFunction method, but we are dealing with a LinkedList. When I try to "convert" the variables into "linked list friendly" ones, I get type mismatch errors, basically saying I can't use an Object and an Int in a calculation, or that I can't convert an Object into type int and so forth. So I'm really confused on what I'm supposed to do to meet the requirements of the assignment....

Here is a link to the sample code I am looking at, this is also the reference my instructor sent me to look at: http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/03/java-hash-table/   I am looking specifically at his "hashFunction2" method, I would copy the code snippet in here, but it doesn't show up correctly.

So, not only do I not exactly understand what the assignment details are asking me to do, the way I do somewhat understand it doesn't make sense. Make a hash table using the ID field of the contributor data....but then what? I know the key of the hash table is supposed to be the ID, and is the "value" supposed to be the rest of the contributor data? I believe the overall goal is to be able to use this hash table to search for specific contributor data, however, the contributor data is stored in a LinkedList, and when I try to pass that to the hash table, I get errors because I'm dealing with Objects. Super confused as to what to do and my instructor isn't much help, the examples he keeps sending me are super simple and do not really follow the flow of the assignment...any help would be hugely appreciated, this assignment is due Monday. Sorry for the book, but if you do need more information please let me know and I'll post what I know

Comment: Go to office hours and ask your questions. We are not going to be able to help you because you do not understand the requirements enough to formulate a coherent question. We would just be guessing, not answering.

Comment: I've asked my instructor several times, and all he sends me is "sample" code which doesn't remotely answer my questions....my main question is "what is this assignment really asking me to do?" and I posted the assignment details...so I'm not sure how I didn't formulate a coherent question with all of the information I posted...

Comment: @ChrisJohnson ignore the link that you found, it's probably just adding to your confusion. From the brief it looks like the assignment IS to create your own implementation of a hash table. So probably best to read up on what hash tables are and how they work, then attempting to implement it.

Comment: Agreed, and I have done nothing but research hash tables and how to implement them for the last 3 days...I understand the concept of hash tables, and I can create one, however, in this specific scenario, we are dealing with a Linked List, one of the Objects is the ID of the contributor, which we are supposed to use as the Key to the Hash Table, if I'm following along correctly....that part I get and isn't hard. The hard part is what is the "value" side of the hash table? Is it supposed to point to the rest of the contibutor info? if so, how, since that is an Object and not a String or array...

Comment: Also, that link was provided to me by my instructor...who I am starting to think is not a programmer, or a very good one, considering he keeps dodging my questions by just sending me these sample codes and stuff...he sent me the "Solution to this assignment" earlier...nowhere in the code was there a hash table...one is referenced, but never really used or implemented...